# I tried to install dual boot the new Ubuntu version but i have reached a error before install "sgx disabled by bios"

Tags: dual-boot, software-installation, sgx

I have an Acer Aspire 5 with Windows 11. I tried to install Ubuntu new version but I have reached this error:

```
sgx disabled by bios
```

The error screen:

[image: the error screen]

Answer (score 0):

You should enable SGX in your BIOS settings. To do so so:

1. Boot laptop into BIOS mode
   a) repeatedly press F9 while powering on
   b) From Windows Setting >  Update & security >  Update and recovery > Recovery > Restart now > Troubleshoot > Advanced options > UEFI Firmware Settings > Restart
2. Navigate to Security tab (or some similar name)
3. Find SGX and enable it

Comment: i reached security option on bios setup but it doesn't have this option